# Unlimited rows in a grid container

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I want to display an endless number of divs.

I want each div to be on new line.

For example now in wrapper I am setting:

```
wrap {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: repeat(4, [row] 25px);
}
```

And for each div I am setting:

```
div1 { grid-row: "row" },
div2 { grid-row: "row 2"}
```

....etc...

How can I deal with it in CSS? What if I have 99999 divs? I can't manually for each div setting `div[№] { grid-row: "row №" }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each grid item to occupy the entire row, then basically you're asking for a single-column grid container.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>1</grid-item>
  <grid-item>2</grid-item>
  <grid-item>3</grid-item>
  <grid-item>4</grid-item>
  <grid-item>5</grid-item>
  <grid-item>etc.</grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

With `grid-template-columns: 1fr`, you're setting the container to a single column which occupies all available space.

You can create rows with the [**`grid-template-rows`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing) property. These rows would be part of the [**explicit grid**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids), which means the rows have been defined.

However, if you don't know how many rows there will be, the grid algorithm can create rows as necessary. These rows are part of the [**implicit grid**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids), which means the rows have not been defined and are created automatically.

If you want to set a height for implicit rows, use the [**`grid-auto-rows`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) property.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}


/* non-essential */
grid-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
grid-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>1</grid-item>
  <grid-item>2</grid-item>
  <grid-item>3</grid-item>
  <grid-item>4</grid-item>
  <grid-item>5</grid-item>
  <grid-item>etc.</grid-item>
</grid-container>
```